# SQL Left Join - Join on one condition, default to another condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing a join between two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Thing thing
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ThingDetails details 
        ON (a.id = details.thing_id AND details.thing_language = 'Spanish')
```

This will basically give me all entries in table 'Thing' with details in Spanish - if there is no details in Spanish, it will give me null values.

What I want to do is "fallback" to English for a Thing if there is no entry in ThingDetails for Spanish i.e. if `ON (a.id = details.thing_id AND details.thing_language = 'Spanish')` fails.

Is there a way I can easily accomplish this? Essentially knowing if the right side of the left join is null?

Comment: So, if there is a 'Spanish' record you want to fetch that. If not, you'll settle for the 'English' record?

Comment: @Error_2646 Exatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `left join`s and `coalesce()

```
SELECT t.*,
       COALESCE(tds.col, tde.col) as as col
FROM Thing t LEFT JOIN
     ThingDetails tds 
     ON t.id = tds.thing_id AND tds.thing_language = 'Spanish' LEFT JOIN
     ThingDetails tde
     ON t.id = tde.thing_id AND tde.thing_language = 'English' AND tds.thing_id IS NULL;
```

The `LEFT JOIN`s bring the data together.  The `COALESCE()` chooses the appropriate value of the column you care about.  Add more `COALESCE()` rows if you have more columns that you care about.

EDIT:

If you don't want to list the columns, you can do:

```
select t.*, td.*
from Thing t left joi
     (select td.*,
             row_number() over (partition by thing_id
                                order by case when td.thing_language = 'Spanish' then 1 else 2 end
                               ) as seqnum
      from ThingDetails td
      where thing_language in ('Spanish', 'English')
     ) td
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to COALESCE() all columns in ThingDetails?

Comment: @Harry . . . Alas, there isn't.  In Oracle 12+, you can use a lateral join which would simplify the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can join to the table twice. Once for your desired language and once for your default language. Then use `COALESCE()` in your select to do the defaulting:

```
SELECT thing.*, COALESCE(details_spanish.some_field, details_default.some_field) as some_field 
FROM Thing thing
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ThingDetails details_spanish
        ON (a.id = details.thing_id AND details.thing_language = 'Spanish')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ThingDetails details_default 
        ON (a.id = details.thing_id AND details.thing_language = 'English')
```